# Does a statically linked libcurl still use dynamically linked libraries?

Tags: c++, libcurl, static-linking, dynamic-linking

*Disclaimer: I am a newbie who is trying to learn about how to use third party libraries. *

I’m looking at using libcurl for a project and I want to statically link it to my project so that it is included in my final executable.

Some documentation online says:

> By default, configure will setup the build files so that the following make file command will create both shared and static versions of libcurl. You can change that with the `—disable-static` and `—disabled-shared` options to configure.
>
> If you instead want to build with static versions of third party libraries instead of shared libraries, you need to prepare yourself for an uphill battle....

Are they talking about the libraries that libcurl uses? I guess what I’m asking is: even if I build libcurl and link statically, will libcurl still be linking dynamically to 3rd party libraries?

Is that what this is saying?

Comment: You absolutely can statically link `libcurl`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: But what good does static linking do if libcurl depends on dynamic libraries? I guess I’m missing something.

Comment: It doesn't depend on dynamic libraries, it's a chunk of code you can statically link in your executable if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if it did include dynamically linked code? Or would that not make sense for a library like that?

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, a static library is really nothing more than an archive of object files. Linking with a static library is the same as linking with the separate object files themselves. That means that any 3rd party dependency that the library have also becomes a dependency for your application. And you must link with those 3rd party libraries and dependencies when you link your application.

Now for libcurl itself, depending on how you configure and build libcurl, it may depend on some 3rd party libraries that *can't* be linked statically to your application.

So to answer your question: It depends.

It mostly depends on how you configure it for building, and what 3rd party libraries you tell it to use, and if those 3rd party libraries are available as static libraries (and then on to *their* dependencies and so on).

Comment: Oh man....so maybe I don’t understand dynamic linking as well as I should. I just have more questions. It seems almost like why would you ever want to link anything dynamically. Isn’t that like betting that the person running the program will have that library installed somewhere? Maybe that’s a stupid question. I feel like I can’t find any explanations that are getting through to me.

Comment: You can use `ldd` to see what dynamic libraries your compiled code depends on. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html. See also `lddtree`. https://codeyarns.com/tech/2015-12-16-how-to-view-hierarchy-of-shared-library-dependencies-using-lddtree.html

Comment: @pocketonion "Dynamic linking" to libraries is useful if you remember that such libraries are also called *shared* libraries. That means every program using that library *share* a single instance of the library. If you link statically, then all program will have their own copy of the library, which waste a lot of space (both on disk and definitely in memory).